# How can I interact via command line with my GCP Cloud SQL db deployed via App Engine with Sequelize ORM?

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-platform, sequelize.js, google-cloud-sql, sequelize-cli

Having a hard time figuring out how or where I can run queries directly to the db?
I specifically want to see the files in `SequelizeMeta` to see its migration history.

Comment: for GCP you need the "cloud sql proxy" to connect to a database. The proxy opens a connection for you and maps the port to 5432 for example. Now you can use a query tool to login and query the database. Here is the link to the proxy https://cloud.google.com/sql/docs/mysql/sql-proxy P.S. the database needs to have a public IP if you want to connect from your home computer, there's an option for that in the GCP console

Comment: Thank you very much.  Im now getting the error `psql: FATAL:  connection requires a valid client certificate
FATAL:  pg_hba.conf rejects connection for host ""xx.xxx.xxx.xx" user "yyyyy", database "postgres", SSL off` is it because the new IP address from which im trying to connect hasnt been whitelisted yet?

Comment: I think it expects an SSL certificate, so either you have to change it in the GCP console that you allow connections without ssl or you have to provide an ssl certificate. Also check your tool with which you try to login if it has ssl on or off

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With the great lead from @tclass -
If you want to interact with your postgresql db via GCP, go to your GCP console that is connected to your Cloud SQL and open the terminal from the top right, then run `gcloud sql connect <DB instance ID here/> --user=postgres`.  If you get the error I wrote in the comments, then you are attempting to connect to a db instance that only allows SSL connections.  GCP Sql proxy cannot connect using SSL, so you will have to allow connections without SSL under the `Connections` tab in your SQL instance details page.  After turning this off, you will be able to connect.

Comment: Small clarification: The SQL Proxy ALWAYS connects with SSL, but that's different than the checkbox in the Cloud SQL settings which says only allow connections with SSL. The Proxy uses the API call `createEphemeral()` in order to securely connect using SSL.

Comment: appreciate the clarification but I dont know how its true? It was only when I checked `Allow unsecure connections` (no SSL) that I was able to connect via the GCP console.  Would appreciate some clarification, and would love to not have to check `Allow unsecure connections` whenever I want to interact with the db on GCP.

Comment: Yeah, that's not worded great...all that means is that you're allowing connections for which you aren't explicitly setting up your own SSL. For example, the same applies even if you're connecting over Private IP on the internal VPC. If you don't have that checked, then you can't connect even though that connection is clearly not unsecure.